# Отладчик для php-скриптов

Tags: отладка, php

Здравствуйте! Подскажите, пожалуйста, есть ли отладчик для php-скриптов, который можно использовать на удаленном сервере, т.е. для скриптов, находящихся на сервере платного хостинга?

Comment: [xdebug][1]


  [1]: http://xdebug.org/

Answer (score 1):

PHP отладчиков, которые вы имеете ввиду, всего два:
 - zend debugger
 - xdebug

Если на хостинге настроено их подключение к PHP, то можно использовать. Если нет - то увы. Но я очень сомневаюсь что они там есть.

Answer (score 0):

Пишите отладочную информацию в файл, например через [error_log](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.error-log.php)

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но это не совсем то, что мне нужно, т.к. хотелось бы выизуальный редактор.

Comment: Я так понимаю, речь идет о виртуальном хостинге? Так вот для этого варианта другого не получится.